# asp.net menu with submenu items, redirect by code behind

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

I have a menu control with 2 levels of menu items!
I would like to navigate via code behind OnMenuItemClick event because when i use NavigationUrl property my ajax UpdateProgress wont start!

The Problem is, whatever submenu item i click, when the event raises it gets every time the first item?!

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" onmenuitemclick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" >
...
    <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="WorkFlows">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Overview" Value="Workflow"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Workflow"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Create" Value="Workflow"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="Workflow"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>

    <asp:MenuItem Text="HoursOfBusiness">
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Overview" Value="HoursOfBusiness"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="HoursOfBusiness"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Create" Value="HoursOfBusiness"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" Value="HoursOfBusiness"></asp:MenuItem>
    </asp:MenuItem>


    </Items>
    </asp:Menu>

protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.Item.Value)
            {
                case "Workflow":
                    switch (e.Item.Text)
                    {
                        case "Overview":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/Workflow.aspx");
                            break;
                            case "Edit":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowEdit.aspx");
                            break;
                            case "Create":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowCreate.aspx");
                            break;
                            case "Delete":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowDelete.aspx");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "HoursOfBusiness":
                    switch (e.Item.Text)
                    {
                        case "Overview":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Edit":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Create":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHoursCreate.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Delete":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
```

so when i click Create under HoursOfBusiness i get the Overview menuItem send to the event?!
I hope the explanation is understandable?! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="WorkFlows">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Overview" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Create" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="HoursOfBusiness">
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Overview" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Create" />
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Delete" />
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

And the code behind is like this:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    bool hasParent = (e.Item.Parent != null);

    switch (hasParent)
    {
        case false:
            switch (e.Item.Value)
            {
                case "WorkFlows":
                    Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/Workflow.aspx");
                    break;
                case "HoursOfBusiness":
                    Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case true:
            switch (e.Item.Parent.Value)
            {
                case "WorkFlows":
                    switch (e.Item.Value)
                    {
                        case "Overview":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/Workflow.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Edit":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowEdit.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Create":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowCreate.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Delete":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/WorkflowDelete.aspx");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "HoursOfBusiness":
                    switch (e.Item.Value)
                    {
                        case "Overview":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Edit":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Create":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHoursCreate.aspx");
                            break;
                        case "Delete":
                            Response.Redirect("~/RGS/Workflow/BusinessHour/BusinessHours.aspx");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;

    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help! it works now!!  but i dont understand why?  the main difference is that u check the value property but u dont set them ?     btw: thanks for the first level menu switch case :-)

Comment: If you don't set the value of your menuitem automatically the name of the item will be used as value. The problem you had is that you cannot check the Text property of your menuitem in code behind. I don't know the reason for that but checking the Value will work. So when you run your code you can only get "Workflows" or "HoursOfBusiness" and not the actual text of the menuitem itself. So I solved this by make the value the actual value of the text (by leaving it empty) and check for the parrent. Hopefully this answer makes my solution a little bit more clear to you.