# Bind/naviagte menu items in web forms (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, menuitem

I am new to ASP.net web forms. Please help me for following issue.

Dragged menu control in the design. Edited menu items with its sub items. I have a grid view with the data bound to the database. When I select the sub menu item the gridview with the data should be shown below the menu. How to show he gridview when I select a menu item

I tried to bind the grid view id but it doesn't work.

```
      <asp:Menu ID="mini" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Items> <asp:MenuItem Text="Item">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="sdaad" Value="1">
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub" ></asp:MenuItem>
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub1" Value="MenuSub1" ></asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" Value="Item">
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub"></asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem>
              </asp:MenuItem></Items>
      </asp:Menu>
```

I want to show the gridview when the menu item is selected

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table-condensed" runat="server" DataKeyNames="projectid" OnRowCommand="Unnamed_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proje">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbfid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("projectid")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doc">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbfname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("video")%>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("abstract")%>' >download</asp:HyperLink>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

In my page load event

```
con.Open();


    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    con.Close();
```

Please help me

Comment: Have you tried just to use bootstrap? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp I hope you can program yourself dynamic creating of subitems

Comment: But my issue is : I want to disable the main menu click. Only in the sub menu items the events should be handled.

Comment: Let's think in other way. You need to create menu and disable main menu, I'm approaching you to generate menu's programmatically. But you may do your main menu item as static, and generate all sub menu's programmatically. In that case you will have just a link to main page, and links to you special sub items's you may use as you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think This will help you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <form runat="server" id="form1">
       <asp:Menu OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" ID="mini" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Items> <asp:MenuItem Text="Item">
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="GetUser" Value="1">
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub" ></asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub1" Value="MenuSub1" ></asp:MenuItem>
                  </asp:MenuItem>
                  <asp:MenuItem Text="Item" Value="Item">
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="MenuSub" Value="MenuSub"></asp:MenuItem>
                  </asp:MenuItem>
                  </asp:MenuItem></Items>
          </asp:Menu>

             <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table-condensed" runat="server" DataKeyNames="projectid" >
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proje">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbfid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("projectid")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Doc">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbfname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("video")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("abstract")%>' >download</asp:HyperLink>

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
            </form>

    </body>  
    </html>  


   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class AutoCompleteCity : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your database connection");
        if(mini.SelectedItem.Value=="1")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [order]",conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The event fires when I click on main menu. I want to select submenu item but it start execution on the first click on main menu. With your code the if condition will go false. How to solve it

Comment: when you click on the menu it checks **mini.SelectedItem.Value=="1"**  and only GetUser have value==1 you can put mini.SelectedItem.Value=="1" || mini.SelectedItem.Value=="MenuSub"|| mini.SelectedItem.Value=="MenuSub1" and so on...... in Condition. 

   If you want to execute code on all menu items then remove the condition

Comment: But I want particularly the sub item. The main menu is only to view the content. It should not execute when I click main menu

Comment: [asp.net menu with submenu items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711891/asp-net-menu-with-submenu-items-redirect-by-code-behind)   Look at this